# sql query when count = 0 return another select

Tags: sql, subquery

I have this query that returns a set of data. I have a problem tho. I need to check if the returned set of data have rows or not.

If it returns 0 rows, I need to select the same data with different conditions.
If it returns more than 0 rows, I keep the data from the first set of data. I placed a c# like pseudocode where I am having trouble figuring how to return my data.

```
  declare @Nousager as int = 3
    DECLARE @tableVerification AS TABLE
        (
            id int,
            Nom  VARCHAR(50)
        )
  INSERT INTO @tableVerification
  select distinct c.id,c.Nom from Categorie_Equipement c
  join Utilisateurs u on u.id = @Nousager
  join Utilisateurs_Groupe ug on ug.NoUsager =  u.id
  join Groupe_Equipements ge on ge.noGroupe = ug.noGroupe



     --if (tableVerification.Count == 0){
    select id,Nom from Categorie_Equipement c
  --}else keep @tableVerification
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this check with an `If Not Exists` to see if the table has been populated.  If it hasn't (meaning no rows were returned by the first query) populate the table with the second query.

```
Declare @Nousager           As Int = 3
Declare @tableVerification  As Table
(
    id  Int,
    Nom Varchar (50)
)

Insert Into @tableVerification
Select  Distinct c.id, c.Nom 
From    Categorie_Equipement    c
Join    Utilisateurs            u   on  u.id = @Nousager
Join    Utilisateurs_Groupe     ug  on  ug.NoUsager = u.id
Join    Groupe_Equipements      ge  on  ge.noGroupe = ug.noGroupe

If Not Exists (Select * From @tableVerification)
Begin
    Insert  @tableVerification
    Select  id, Nom 
    From    Categorie_Equipement
End
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you very much!